# Netbeans крашится

Tags: ide, netbeans

Возникла проблема. После некоторого времени работы в netBeans он крашится, не выдавая при этом никаких ошибок.
Пробовал установить более старую версию, переустановить java - не помогло (версии IDE 7.3 и 8.0).

Может, кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Как это можно исправить? Гугол не помог.

**Обновление**

Win7 enterprise. Крашится, как правило, при работе с php-файлами в проекте.

Comment: Какая ось, что делаете в момент креша?

Comment: Такая же проблема NB 8.0.1 PHP. Windows 7

Comment: Проверьте на вирусы. Скачайте более позднюю версию IDE.